# How can I escape the format string?

Tags: python, string, string.format

Is it possible to use Python's `str.format(key=value)` syntax to replace only certain keys.

Consider this example:

```
my_string = 'Hello {name}, my name is {my_name}!'

my_string = my_string.format(name='minerz029')
```

which returns

```
KeyError: 'my_name'
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a simpler workaround which I use:

```
my_string = 'Hello {name}, my name is {my_name}!'

to_replace = {
    "search_for" : "replace_with",
    "name" : "minerz029",
}

for search_str in to_replace:
    my_string = my_string.replace('{' + search_str + '}', to_replace[search_str])

print(my_string)
```

This can be expanded easily with more keys in the `to_replace` dict and wont complain even if the search string doesn't exist. It could probably be improved to offer more of `.format()`'s features, but it was enough for me.

Answer (score 17):

You can escape `my_name` using double curly brackets, like this

```
>>> my_string = 'Hello {name}, my name is {{my_name}}!'
>>> my_string.format(name='minerz029')
'Hello minerz029, my name is {my_name}!'
```

As you can see, after formatting once, the outer `{}` is removed and `{{my_name}}` becomes `{my_name}`. If you later want to format `my_name`, you can simply format it again, like this

```
>>> my_string = 'Hello {name}, my name is {{my_name}}!'
>>> my_string = my_string.format(name='minerz029')
>>> my_string
'Hello minerz029, my name is {my_name}!'
>>> my_string.format(my_name='minerz029')
'Hello minerz029, my name is minerz029!'
```

Answer (score 8):

Python3.2+ has `format_map` which lets you do this

```
>>> class D(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, k):return '{'+k+'}'
... 
>>> my_string = 'Hello {name}, my name is {my_name}!'
>>> my_string.format_map(D(name='minerz029'))
'Hello minerz029, my name is {my_name}!'
>>> _.format_map(D(my_name='minerz029'))
'Hello minerz029, my name is minerz029!'
```

Now it's not necessary to add extra `{}`, only the keys you provide to `D` will be substituted

As @steveha points out, if you are on an older Python3 you can still use

```
my_string.format(**D(name='minerz029'))
```

Comment: I just tested this, and you don't need to use `str.format_map(d)`; you can use `str.format(**d)` and it works just fine.  However, `.format_map()` is more efficient as it doesn't need to make a copy of the dict.

Comment: @steveha, in Python2 still converts it to a `dict`, but it works ok for Python3

Comment: Right... I tested in Python3.  Python2 doesn't have `.format_map()`.  I just meant that in Python versions that have `.format_map()` you can actually use `str.format(**d)` instead and it will also work.  Sorry for not spelling that out.

Comment: The use of a `dict` subclass here that defines `__missing__` is a most elegant solution.